# Urllib HTTP Error 403

Tags: python, urllib, http-error, urlopen

I've searched through the forums to try and figure out why the following code was not working:

```
import nltk, re, pprint
from urllib import request
url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554.txt"
response = request.urlopen(url)
raw = response.read().decode('utf8')
print(raw[:75])
```

But have thus far been unsuccessful in resolving things. Here are some similar solutions I tried to implement to no avail:
[Forum 1,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877619/python3-urllib-error-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden)
[Forum 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627227/http-error-403-in-python-3-web-scraping)

The error I get is:

```
 File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
response = meth(req, response)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
 File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you considered using `requests` instead?

Comment: Looks similar to [urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden/46213623#46213623)

Answer (score 3):

This code works:

*Python 2*

```
from  urllib import urlopen

url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554.txt"
response = urlopen(url)

if response.code == 200:
    raw = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    print raw[:75]
else:
    print 'Error', response.code

response.close()
```

Response:

> The Project Gutenberg EBook of Crime and Punishment, by Fyodor Dostoevsky

*Python 3*

```
from  urllib import request

url = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2554/2554.txt"

try:
    response = request.urlopen(url)
    raw = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    print(raw[:75])
except Exception as ex:
    print('Error:', ex)
```

If you get HTTP code 403, it mean that you forbidden from access this url.

Comment: Seems like OP is using Python 3. Update your answer for Python 3 version of urllib or this might just lead to more confusion